# Why EVA display of views is added to the manage display of content type?

Tags: views, nodes, entities

There are three related content types in my website: article, sub-article, number-article. there is an entity reference from `number-article` to the `sub-article` and an entity reference from `sub-article` to the `article`. There are two views that displays these relations and in each one there is an EVA display. in the manage display of `sub-article` content type I saw this:

[image]

content of `numberarticle` is set to `all content types`, so why a display if view is added to a content type and how does Drupal find out where it should be?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [EVA project page](https://drupal.org/project/eva):

> "Eva" is short for "Entity Views Attachment;" it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity.

(...)

> The placement of the view in the entity's content can be reordered on the "Field Display" administration page for that entity, like other fields added using the Field UI module.

Apparently it did just what it claims it does.

Comment: It has been a long time I've been using this module but I didn't know this thing. thanks